# What is the standard way of preconfiguring Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a significant amount of pre-configuration that I want to automate for Jenkins. E.g. Pre configuring gerrit for the gerrit trigger plugins, pre configuring saml, libraries etc

I'm aware of two methods typically used to do similar tasks:

- Configuration as code plugin + yaml configuration
- Groovy scripts to execute from the init.groovy.d directory of jenkins home on Jenkins startup

My users want to be able to update Jenkins configuration from the UI without needing to update yaml, suggesting the config as code plugin isn't fit for our purpose as I believe it reapplies the config when the Jenkins container is restarted.

My hunch is to use groovy scripts that remove themselves after the first execution so that they don't reapply themselves on restart.

Is there a more standard way of pre configuring Jenkins? or is groovy my best bet?

Comment: When you say, pre configuring jenkis, do you mean: Create jobs in Jenkins?

Comment: Creating a job is one example. A few more would be configuring global variables, pipeline libraries and settings for various plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR: Use the file system

Why? There is no "standard" way to achieve what you intend; the two approaches that you suggest are viable options for sure.

From operational point of view, however, it will be good to select a solution which is

1. *generic* (so it can cover all aspects of Jenkins configuration) and
2. "*simple*" to use

Now,

- "Configuration as code" makes you depend on the corresponding plugin -- it may or may not support a specific configuration option
- With groovy, it is sometimes quite difficult to find out how to set a Jenkins configuration option (and how to store the setting permanently).

Since **all Jenkins configuration data is stored on-disk**, another option for bootstrapping Jenkins with a well-defined configuration is to **pre-fill those configuration files with proper content** right away:

- You can be sure that this works in *all* cases, including all border cases (like, secret/encrypyted data)
- Users can change the data later on as needed
- Usually, it's quite easy to find the proper configuration file

On the downside, there is a risk that the configuration file format might change with newer versions of the core or of some plugin. However, a similar risk exists for the two other solutions that you suggested.

Tip: for rolling out such pre-configured Jenkins setups, it is helpful to disable the Jenkins setup wizard by setting `jenkins.install.runSetupWizard` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

When you combine words like : pre-configuring Jenkins, init.groovy.d, jenkins home, jenkins startup, etc, it sounds confusing o_O

When Jenkins is ready to use, **usual folks just need to create jobs or pipelines**. If you need to create a job or pipeline, you just need to install and configure some plugins. Very few of them need groovy, because the goal is "Easy to use".

Advanced user are able to create its own plugins, with java. But almost all is available as plugins.

You can use groovy in a pipeline scripts or declarative pipelines.

So if your question is more like "What is the best way to create and configure jobs or pipelines", I can advise you:

- Try much as possible to use pipeline scripts or declarative pipelines.
- Use just verified and supported plugins.
- Stop call shell scripts in hard drive.
- Stop using complicated configurations. Almost all of requirements are already implemented and documented.
- If you have a requirement and no one plugin seems to help you, ask here in stackoverflow or develop your own plugin focused in **configurability**, so you can release it, for the benefit of Jenkins Community.

Comment: I need to configure Jenkins prior to it starting up for the first time. I know of pipelines bit that doesn't help me with configuration.

Comment: Latest releases of jenkins have a wizard installation, which offer a lots of  widely used plugins. I think you dont need to pre-configure your jenkins to develop a job or pipeline. Let us an example of your requirement in your question.

Comment: The wizard isn't fit for my requirements. I need to select and configure the plugins programmatically. I've disabled the wizard.