# Automating setup and configuration of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

Below are my requirements:

Setup Jenkins post deployment with following items:

1. Adding secrets.
2. Adding Users
3. Adding projects
4. Configuring cloud (kubernetes setup)
5. Installing plugins.

I have been doing these manually and am at a point where it makes more sense to automate it using jenkins cli or some configuration management.

I have tried looking up documents and tutorials and most of them just show the manual process of doing it.

Comment: What have you [looked at](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-automate-jenkins-setup-with-docker-and-jenkins-configuration-as-code) ? *JCasC, *JobDSL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the standard way of preconfiguring Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417095/what-is-the-standard-way-of-preconfiguring-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a running pod with the desired configuration, you can first extract the jenkins home:

```
kubectl copy <namespace>/<pod-name>:~/.jenkins /any/local/folder
```

Then one of the most straight forward way might be to use an init container with a volume mount which would retrieve your jenkins home from a remote location (S3 for instance):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deploy
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-script-downloader
        image: aws
        args:
          - "s3"
          - "cp"
          - "s3://some-bucket/path-to-your-folder-config"
          - "/tmp/config"
          - "--recursive"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /tmp/config
      containers:
      - image: jenkins
        name: jenkins
        ....
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: ~/.jenkins
      volumes:
      - name: config
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jenkins-config-pvc
```

NB: If your s3 (or any storage system) is private you will also have to mount a secret.